# FreeBSD - Can't access jail from SSH

Tags: ssh, authentication, freebsd, jail

I need your help for solving an SSH+FreeBSD+jails authentication issue.

I've (almost) successfully set up a jailed environment on my FreeBSD 8.2 box.

My FreeBSD host has 2 network interfaces: 192.168.1.41/24 (regular network) and 172.16.100.41/24 (admin network).

Its one and only jail is configured to listen on both 192.168.1.101 and 172.16.100.101 IP addresses. I have configured `sshd` in the jail to listen on the admin interface only (that is, 172.16.100.101).

Everything described above works, but what I can't do is, connecting to the jail via SSH from the host (being logged as `root` on the host). After accepting the public key, I'm asked for a password (which I believe is `root`'s password), and after 3 attempts, I always get the message `"Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)"`.
The same message is logged in the jail's `/var/log/auth.log`.

The following commands all yield the same result:

`ssh 172.16.100.101`

`ssh root@172.16.100.101`

`ssh -l root 172.16.100.101`

I'm expecting the jail's `root` password to be the same as my host's `root` password, right?
What am I missing? Or where should I be looking for more hints?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should confirm that the password set correctly by either manually copying the files in as Robert Novak suggests, or login to the jail with `jexec ${jailID} /bin/tcsh` and `passwd` (you can use `jls` to find out the jail ID).

Also, verify that `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

EDIT: After you edit or copy `/etc/master.passwd`, you need to run `/usr/sbin/pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd` to tell FreeBSD to remake the binaries based on the new file(s).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. See my answer to Robert Novak, I indeed had to explicitly `PermitRootLogin yes` in the `sshd` config file, but I still don't understand why I also need to reset `root`'s password.

Comment: OK so I found out that you actually need to copy 4 files: `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/master.passwd` and their binary counterparts: `/etc/pwd.db` and `/etc/spwd.db`. Otherwise I guess the state is inconsistent between these pairs, and nothing works until you reset the password using `passwd`!

Answer (score 1):

Each jail should have its own passwd file. If you copied the host's /etc/master.passwd and /etc/passwd into the jails, then the passwords would be identical. Otherwise, I believe you will have to reset the password manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As Jed Daniels pointed out, I also had to edit `sshd`'s config file to allow `root` login. Fair enough. But, following your advice, I've also added both `/etc/master.passwd` and `/etc/passwd` to my "base" jail (I'm using `ezjail` so I've set up my own flavour). However it turns out that even with these files copied to a new jail, I still need to issue a `jexec #j passwd` to reset `root`'s password. If I compare the host's `/etc/master.passwd` to the jail's `/etc/master.passwd`, I can see that the line corresponding to `root` is different, even with the same password. Why?